# Getting undefined but I would like to use else statement inside for loop and display 'not exist' instead

Tags: javascript

How can I use else statement in the following, would like to replace undefined to 'not exist', tried but not working. program: Check a given string contains 2 to 4 numbers of a specified character

```js
function check_char(x, y) {
  for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
    var d = y[j];
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    data = x[i]
    console.log(data)
    if (data == d) {
      return d + " exist";
    }
  }
}

document.write(check_char("Python", "y") + "<br>");
document.write(check_char("JavaScript", "a") + "<br>");
document.write(check_char("Console", "o") + "<br>");
document.write(check_char("Console", "C") + "<br>");
document.write(check_char("Console", "e") + "<br>");
document.write(check_char("JavaScript", "S") + "<br>");
```

```
**output:** 
y exist
a exist
o exist
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: `y` shouldn't exist should it?

Comment: @Andy `y` exists in `Python`

Comment: _"Check a given string contains 2 to 4 numbers of a specified character"_: "Python" only has one "y". @GrafiCode

Comment: @Andy you're right, reading the question again I realized it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function check_char(x, y) {
  for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
    var d = y[j];
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    data = x[i]
    console.log(data)
    if (data == d) {
      return d + " exist";
    }
  }
  return 'not exist';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking you don't need the `else`. Keep a count of the number of times the character appears in the string. If the count >= 2 and <= 4 return "exists" otherwise just return "does not exist".

You should [avoid using `document.write`](https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2016/09/avoid-using-document-write-scripts-injection/). This example has an extra function that creates [some HTML using the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) returned from the `checkChar` function, and then uses [`insertAdjacentHML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add it to the page.

```js
function checkChar(str, char) {
  
  // Initialise the count 
  let count = 0;
  
  // Loop over the string - if the
  // letter in the iteration is the same as
  // the character increment the count
  for (const letter of str) {
    if (letter === char) ++count;
  }
  
  // If the count is within bounds return "exists"
  if (count >=2 && count <=4) {
    return `<span class="red">${char}</span> exists`;
  }
  
  // Otherwise return "does not exist"
  return `<span class="red">${char}</span> does not exist`;

}

function write(str) {

  // Create an HTML paragraph string with the string
  // returned from `checkChar`, and then add that
  // to the page
  const para = `<p>${str}</p>`;
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', para);
}

write(checkChar('Python', 'y'));
write(checkChar('JavaScript', 'a'));
write(checkChar('Console', 'o'));
write(checkChar('Console', 'C'));
write(checkChar('Console', 'e'));
write(checkChar('JavaScript', 'S'));
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```